# Linear Search - Portable Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a major project for SDD. And I am coming across this error. TypeError: LinearSearch() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). I get this error in the 'main' module whenever I try to call the module. Can you please help me? Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkl32.jpg

Comment: please include your code as text.

Comment: Something in `main.py` (on line 35) is calling `linearsearch.LinearSearch(reader())` whereas your `LinearSearch()` function takes two arguments. The error and the traceback are pretty much self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that python is a case-sensitive language.

You were calling LinearSearch with a name linearSearch.

This was Your mistake.

Comment: You could also use python membership datatype to solve this problem you can write numInput in LinearSearch this will return true or false